# How to handle multiple fan-outs using AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have one AWS lambda that kicks off (SNS events) multiple lambdas which in turn kick off (SNS events) multiple lambdas. All of these lambdas are writing files to S3 and I need to know when all files have been written. There will be another lambda which will send a final SNS message containing all references to the files produced. The amount of fan-out in the second set of lambdas is unknown as depends on the first fan-out.

If this was a single fan-out I would know how many files to be looking for but as it is a 2 step fan-out I am unsure as to how to monitor for all files. Has anybody dealt with this before? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @Chris thanks, that looks a lot better.

Comment: Have you considered using Amazon Step Functions to coordinate this process?

Comment: You can see sample implementation from here. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-step-functions-build-distributed-applications-using-visual-workflows/

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I have considered step functions as they seemed like the obvious fit. However my problem is that in order to run a parallel task in step functions you need to know the size of the array. My array for the second set of processes is dynamically sized. I know I could do this sequentially but I am wanting to take advantage of the AWS Lambda concurrency.

Comment: I think you could track all this with a DynamoDB table (one record per initial Lambda invocation), using conditional writes and consistent reads to allow the parallel processes to keep the record updated without stepping on each other. I'd need more details about the entire process though. Does the first Lambda invocation/splitter know how many of the splitter2 invocations will be called?

Comment: @MarkB the first splitter knows how many splitter2's are invoked. The problem is that it is at that  point that splitter2 decides how much to split for a second time. For example this could result in 2 processes or it could result in 14 processes. This is where i am getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a DynamoDB table for tracking this process. Create a single record in the table when the initial Lambda function kicks off, with a unique ID like a UUID or something if you don't already have a unique ID for this process. Also add that unique ID to the SNS messages, this will be the key used for all updates performed by the other processes. Also add a `splitters_invoked` to the record when it is created by the first process with the number of second level splitter functions it is invoking, and a `splitters_complete` property set to 0.

Inside the second level splitter functions you can use the DynamoDB feature **Conditional Updates** to update the DynamoDB record with the list of files created with their S3 locations. The second level splitter functions will also use the DynamoDB **Atomic Counters** feature to update the `splitters_complete` count just before they exit.

At the "process" level, each of those invocations will perform another **Conditional Update** to the DynamoDB record flagging the individual file they just processed as complete.

Finally, configure DynamoDB streams to trigger another Lambda function. This lambda function will check two conditions: `splitters_complete` is equal to `splitters_invoked`, and all files in the file list are marked as "completed". Then it will know that it can perform the final step in your process.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep the list of S3 file locations in the DynamoDB table, simply use atomic counters for that as well, one counter for the total number of files created by the second level splitters, and another counter for the file processing functions.